# Spectrum color picker addon in bootstrap form

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get the spectrum color picker into a bootstrap form on the right side.

Spectrum github:

https://github.com/bgrins/spectrum

It is not working correctly, as can be seen in this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/b5gnupfn/

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">
       <input type='text' class='my_color'/>
  </span>
</div>
```

EDIT:

I just want it to fit neatly into the text form like with other .input-group-addon or .input-group-btn elements in an .input-group. Right now it is odd looking.

EDIT:

Fixed jsfiddle, it is now accurate regarding the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the width, height of sp-replacer, and making it equal the bootstrap form-control makes it fit correctly.

Answer: http://jsfiddle.net/94jcykcp/

```
.sp-replacer {
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
}

.form-control {
    height: 30px !important
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to change the `.input-group-addon` to `.input-group-btn` and add the `.input-group-lg` class to the entire input group.

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
   <span class="input-group-btn" id="basic-addon1">
       <input type='text' class='my_color'/>
   </span>
</div>
```

Here is an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b5gnupfn/1/. I am not sure if this is what you want, but it looks like it works.

Comment: Much better! But I need the carot to be on the right side of the color picker. It seems to get warped to the bottom when in an input-group. Here is a jsfiddle with your solution and the color picker by itself. http://jsfiddle.net/4qa64aqc/

Comment: Maybe it's because our screen sizes are different because it appears on the right side on my screen.

Comment: Interesting, I'm trying to mess with the css to get it right on my screen. It has to do with the width of .sp-replacer, changing it seems to get it to work.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I do not think I know how to fix that, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, your answer actually led me to the solution. Much appreciated!